# About linking error in zlib on ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, zlib

Recently I need to use zlib in programming on Ubuntu and here I have a problem.
I wrote a small program to test zlib functions and I built it in Eclipse.
I found it can be compiled but there were some linking errors like this:

```
main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `compress'
main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `uncompress'
```

What should I do with this? If this is because there is no library file?

Can anyone give some help? Thanks a lot!

MOODY_Y

Plus, here are my building info:

```
11:59:08 **** Build of configuration Debug for project test_zlib ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: test_zlib
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "test_zlib"  ./main.o   
./main.o: In function `main':
/home/hyq/workspace/test_zlib/Debug/../main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `compress'
/home/hyq/workspace/test_zlib/Debug/../main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `uncompress'
collect2: ld return 1
make: *** [test_zlib] error 1

11:59:10 Build Finished (took 1s.715ms)
```

Comment: Show your linker command.

Comment: Did you link against zlib?

Comment: As I said, I just used Eclipse IDE to build it and here is the linker command: g++  -o "test_zlib"  ./main.o

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Also, use `-lz` on the compile/link command.

Comment: I have installed zlib1g-dbg before I started this work. And it told me there is no need to install zlib1g-dev.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link youe source to zlib.Build your code as follows

```
gcc main.cpp -lz
```

Comment: Or rather `g++ -o "test_zlib" ./main.o -lz` as the linker command.